# How can I visualise the result of a graph query in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, graph-visualization

I have just started to explore Neo4j for graph-based analytics. I am trying to work with the below Neo4j example on fraud detection using the shell available in the Neo4j browser:
https://github.com/neo4j-examples/graphgists/blob/master/fraud/bank-fraud-detection.adoc

The query listed in the example (below) return records in a table format.

```
MATCH       (accountHolder:AccountHolder)-[]->(contactInformation)
WITH        contactInformation,
            count(accountHolder) AS RingSize
MATCH       (contactInformation)<-[]-(accountHolder)
WITH        collect(accountHolder.UniqueId) AS AccountHolders,
            contactInformation, RingSize
WHERE       RingSize > 1
RETURN      AccountHolders AS FraudRing,
            labels(contactInformation) AS ContactType,
            RingSize
ORDER BY    RingSize DESC
```

My questions:

1. How can I return the result of this query as a graph?
2. Also, is there a way in which I can highlight a portion of a graph
   with a query?

Answer (score 0):

Neo4j doesn't "return things as a graph" or "return things as a table". Instead, it makes API calls and then parses the JSON results. Neo4j Browser will display is as a graph, as a table, as text, or as code.

To see the results of a query as a graph in Neo4j Browser, click on "Graph" on the left side of the query window. (Note: when you end a query with `ORDER BY` then Neo4j Browser defaults to showing you a table.)